# How can I serialize custom many-to-many model django?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have 3 tables on data base: News, CustomUser(not important) and Comment:

```
class News(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='news_images/', blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, blank=True, default=1)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags, blank=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(
        CustomUser,
        related_name='author',
        through='Comments.Comment',
        blank=True,
    )

class Comment(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    event = models.ForeignKey(News, on_delete=models.CASCADE, parent_link=True)
```

As you can see, the comment is a custom many-to-many model, that links Users and News, and adds some extra data (text of comment itself).
I using DRF, so I need to serialize it. I need news serializer to include list of comments with all their fields(like author fields as you can see below on the screenshot).But when i getting one of the news I see that:

```
{"id":2,"author":{"username":"Admin","email":"alexsiid29@gmail.com","first_name":"","last_name":""},"tags":[],"comments":[1],"date":"15.08.2021 10:10","title":"Тест2","text":"тестовая 2","image":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/news_images/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9.png","published":true}
```

Comments: `"comments":[1]`

And when I printing during the view-function execution:

```
self.object = News.objects.filter(pk=pk).first()
print(self.object.comments.all())
```

I getting this: `<QuerySet [<CustomUser: Admin>]>`
So, instead of a normal representation of comments, I get the authors ID.
There are my serializers:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = CustomUserSerializer(source='author.id')
    event = NewsSerializer(source='event.id')

class NewsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = CustomUserSerializer(read_only=True)
    tags = TagSerializer(required=False, allow_null=True, many=True)
    comments = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_null=True, many=True, read_only=True)
```

So, how can I serialize these tables, or maybe organize them in a different way?

P.S.
I also tried `StringRelatedField` instead of `PrimaryRelatedField`, but it returns author's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have typo in your code: `comments` in `News` model must be linked with `Comment` model, not with `CustomUser`. That's why you get `<QuerySet [<CustomUser: Admin>]>`.
2. To solve "I need news serializer to include list of comments with all their fields", I'd do the following:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = CustomUserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        exclude = ('event',)  # in your particular case


class NewsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = CustomUserSerializer(read_only=True)
    tags = TagSerializer(required=False, allow_null=True, many=True)
    comments = CommentSerializer(many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields = "__all__"
```

I advise you to exclude `event` in `CommentSerializer` because you'll have this info in your `NewsSerializer` so it won't be repeated for each `comment`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for answer. You said that my table should be linked with Comment, but I wrote model following django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany
(There is point Extra fields on many-to-many relationships). Or you suggest some another way (not using ManyToManyField with "throught" parameter)?

Comment: I undarstand you. It's working. Thank you very much!